# Facebooker and Cucumber with IFRAME: Session.current is not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

We just installed Facebooker and Authlogic on a new Rails app, but the Canvas JavaScript limitations persuaded us to choose the iframe to supply our application.
Has anyone been successful using Cucumber and facebooker with an iframe app?

I tried the instructions on

http://opensoul.org/2009/3/6/testing-facebook-with-cucumber

but they don't seem to work.

Specifically, right now the Session.current isn't being set correctly. I get the following error:

```
Given I am logged in as a Facebook user    # features/step_definitions/webrat_steps.rb:6
  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!                                      
  The error occurred while evaluating nil.default_request_params (NoMethodError)                                                                                               
  features/manage_tournaments.feature:7:in `Given I am logged in as a Facebook user'
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Cucumber is not the problem, but WebRat. WebRat is a browser emulator and I don't think it has any iFrame support. I'd advice you to try firewatir or any other 'runner' for cucumber that uses an actual browser with iFrame support.

Comment: Certainly was. Thanks, and sorry for the late response.